# Trouble accessing website without specifying HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: dns, iis

I have a website running on an IIS server located inside our company. It has been running for ages - Windows Server 2012 and IIS. I have started facing a strange issue today. When I try to access the site as "example.com", I get timeout. However, when I do the same and specify the protocol, meaning "http://example.com" or "https://example.com", the site opens just fine.

The webserver is responding to HTTP and HTTPS. Webbrowsers that have accessed the site before do open it even without specifying the protocol, but "fresh" ones, I assume without DNS cache, have the problem above. I have been running the website on this server for ages. The server has not gone through any recent updates or changes of configuration.

The problem is present allways: when trying to access the site from the internet, from within the domain, from computers or mobile phones connected through the carrier. Tested on Chrome, Edge and Firefox. Does not seem to be an issue on Opera.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Does "ping example.com" work in a new computer? Do old computers have some addition in their `hosts` file? Can a new computer that opened the site with `http(s)` then open it without it in a new browser session?

Comment: Yes, ping works. Nothing added to hosts in any of the computers, this should be a regularly publicly accessible website. If I open the site with http(s) explicitly, I can then access it without specifying the protocol while using the same browser.

Comment: What kind of traffic do you see in Wireshark while waiting for the timeout?

Comment: How do you publish the site over DNS? Try this on a new computer : In Chrome go to `chrome://settings/security`, under Advanced, toggle "Use secure DNS", Does this change anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "publish over DNS"?

Comment: I have captured traffic while waiting for the timeout. Anything specific I should be looking for? This is the first time I'm using Wireshark.